# Sending emails with database info using tkinter interface

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter, smtplib

I am still fairly new to Python and I am building an app for work which will automate the sending of details from a MYSQL server db to subscribers. This is an upgrade from the 1st version I built whereby I just ran a python script in the terminal and worked fine but was very limited.

Now I decided to build a GUI using tkinter so that anybody else can use it if they are not tech savvy.

The app has a listbox which gets filled when you search using a simple entry box. Once you select on a business in the entry box, some labels will get automatically filled with more information from the database about that particular business. These labels are: Business name, first name, username, password and email address.

Once you have selected a business you will be able to click on a button which will send the username and password in separate emails to that selected business.

What I have managed to do so far is being able to select a business name in the listbox and the labels to the side gets filled with the information for that business.

What I am really struggling with is when I create the function to 'send' the details, the closest I can get is that it sends 2 emails, to all email addresses that appear in the database (there are only 2 at the moment for testing purposes), with incorrect details. The sending of 2 separate emails is intentional as 1 email should only contain the username and the 2nd email will contain the password.

Code for the selecting the business from the listbox and it filling the labels:

```
# Select business from listbox
def select_business(event):
    selection = event.widget.curselection()
    index = selection[0]
    retailer = businesses[index]
    if not retailer[1]:
        businessname_display_label.config(text=" ")
    else:
        businessname_display_label.config(text=retailer[1])
    if not retailer[3]:
        firstname_display_label.config(text=" ")
    else:
        firstname_display_label.config(text=retailer[3])
    if not retailer[33]:
        username_display_label.config(text=" ")
    else:
        username_display_label.config(text=retailer[33])
    if not retailer[34]:
        password_display_label.config(text=" ")
    else:
        password_display_label.config(text=retailer[34])
    if not retailer[13]:
        email_display_label.config(text=" ")
    else:
        email_display_label.config(text=retailer[13])
```

Here is the function for the button that should send the details:

```
# Send login details button
def send_logins():
    c.execute("""SELECT Retailer_Name, Contact, E_Mail, Account_ID, Password FROM Retailers""")
    users = c.fetchall()
    account_id = users[3]
    user_password = users[4]
    business_name = users[0]
    first_name = users[1]
    email_address = users[2]
    # Create a secure SSL context
    context = ssl.create_default_context()
    with smtplib.SMTP_SSL(smtp_server, port, context=context) as server:
        try:
            server.login(sender_email, password)
        except SMTPAuthenticationError:
            print("Username and/or password you entered is incorrect")
        try:
            missing = []
            print(users)
            for Retailer_Name, Contact, E_Mail, Account_ID, Password in users:
                valid = True
                if not Retailer_Name:
                    missing.append("Business has no name!")
                    valid = False
                if not Account_ID:
                    missing.append("Business has no username!")
                    valid = False
                if not Password:
                    missing.append("Business has no password!")
                    valid = False
                if not E_Mail:
                    missing.append("Business has no email address!")
                    valid = False
                if valid:
                    server.sendmail(
                            sender_email,
                            E_Mail,
                            message.as_string().format(
                                business_name=business_name,
                                first_name=first_name,
                                E_Mail=E_Mail,
                                account_id=account_id,
                                user_password=user_password),
                    )
                    server.sendmail(
                            sender_email,
                            E_Mail,
                            message2.as_string().format(
                                business_name=business_name,
                                first_name=first_name,
                                email_address=email_address,
                                account_id=account_id,
                                user_password=user_password),
                    )
                    if valid:
                        print("Emails sent to " + str(first_name) + " at " + str(business_name))
                print(missing)
        except SMTPException as e2:
            print(e2)
        except Exception as e:
            print("Emails not sent!")
            print(e)
```

Below is the part of the code which allowed me to send emails out using the non-GUI version as I was connected to a csv file on my laptop as I had no way to store all information at that time. Now that I can access all info in one place, I seem to be struggling:

```
# Create a secure SSL context
context = ssl.create_default_context()
with smtplib.SMTP_SSL(smtp_server, port, context=context) as server:
    try:
        server.login(sender_email, password)
    except SMTPAuthenticationError:
        print("Username and/or password you entered is incorrect")
    try:
        with open("contacts2.csv", encoding="UTF-8-SIG", newline='') as file: # Sending Multiple Personalized Emails using a CSV file
            reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=',')
            next(reader)  # Skip header row
            missing = []
            for Retailer, Retailer_Name, Outlet_Group, Segment, First_Name, Email in reader:
                valid = True
                if not Retailer.strip():
                    missing.append("Retailer " + Retailer + " has Retailer ID missing!")
                    valid = False
                if not Retailer_Name.strip():
                    missing.append("Retailer " + Retailer + " has Retailer name missing!")
                    valid = False
                if not Email.strip():
                    missing.append("Retailer " + Retailer + " has Email missing!")
                    valid = False
                if retailer_id != Retailer:
                    missing.append("Retailer " + Retailer + " does not match in file!")
                    valid = False
                if valid:
                    server.sendmail(
                            sender_email,
                            Email.split(';')
```

Hope there is enough information here for any help!

Comment: So the problem is it's sending incorrect details in the two messages? Have you verified that information you're getting from the db via `c.fetchall()` is correct?

Comment: @martineau correct. 2 separate emails get sent. 1 email is for username and the 2nd is for password. However, the parts that get populated in the email template appear in a tuple I think and includes the 4 'variables' I have selected in the SQL statement (Retailer name, First name/contact, email, account_id, password). It doesn't select the details that match in the labels. It just takes the 1st entry in the database. When I print c.fetchall, looks like it returns results as a list in square brackets: [('Business name1, None, None, None, None), ('Business name2, None, None, None, None)....]

Comment: @martineau It also sends the 2 separate emails to all the email addresses in the system but should only be sent to the email address and details that match in the labels.

Comment: That's why I asked about whether you were sure you were getting the correct information from the database — since the only loop in your code is the `for Retailer_Name, Contact, E_Mail, Account_ID, Password in users:`. It hard to understand how this could have been working in the non-GUI version because using tkinter would not have affected that.

Comment: @martineau the difference between the non-GIU version and GUI version is that in the non-GIU version, the email addresses were stored in a csv file as I had no way of storing all the information in the same db. Now that I have all the information in the db, for some reason, I am struggling now that I have all information in one place. I have updated the code above to include the non-GUI code which queried the csv file if that helps.

Comment: Well, you can use the CSV file in the GUI-version, too if you wish. I think your problem has nothing to do with using `tkinter` and is instead about querying the database and getting the information you want out of it properly — so I suggest you get a non-GUI version that doesn't use the CSV working and then add a GUI to *that* so you're only changing one aspect of the program at a time.

Comment: @martineau I wasn't sure whether to state that I am using tkinter or not but wanted to give as much information as possible as it seems to be working with the non-GIU + csv method but not with the GUI + DB method. I don't want to use the CSV file as I will have to keep that updated and would rather only use the db as all the information is there

Comment: The `SELECT` SQL returns all records from the table, but I think you need is one specific record. So you need a `WHERE` clause in the `SELECT` SQL.

Comment: @acw1668 thanks for this. I will play around with the 'WHERE' clause. The thing that is annoying me is that I need emails to go out to the contact details that appears in the labels once I select the business name in the listbox. Therefore I should be somehow adding a 'WHERE' clause that matches one of the details of that particular business?

Comment: I don't know the design of your table, so I just can say that you need the unique field checking in the WHERE clause.  If the business name is the unique key, then use it in the WHERE clause.

Comment: @acw1668 I don't know how but managed to get it right I think! So I added a 'WHERE' clause in the SQL statement as you mentioned and had to pass an argument to the button function using 'lambda' which contained the business details. I have done a couple of tests and it seems to be sending the 2 separate emails with the correct username / password to the email address associated to that particular account! I think I have somehow got there without understanding fully how it is working!